# Bypass redundant code in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, code-duplication

I have two methods in my controller that are called via ajax on click. Both do the exact same thing (retrieving **the same data** from a database) and return a partial view along with the model that contains the retrieved data. The only difference is the view.

```
public PartialViewResult FormA()
{
    [...// Code]

    return PartialView("_FormA", ModelWithData)
}

public PartialViewResult FormB()
{
    [...// same Code as in FormA()]

    return PartialView("_FormB", ModelWithData)
}
```

Both views use the same data but show different things.

If `FormB()` is called `FormA()` definitely has been called before.

There must be a way to bypass the second method/database request. It perceptibly slows down the application due to the additional database request.

My question seems really stupid to me, but I'm not able to find a workaround...

Thx for your help!

Comment: Based on this info I can't say this is definitely good advice, but  it may be that you can cache the results in `FormA` and get them back out in `FormB`. You would introduce a new method that gets from cache or goes to database as necessary.

Comment: If both has the same code you need to store the result in cache or TempData would be a good option to reduce the database request.

Comment: Cant just extract the shared code in a private method? And that would also be where you could cache the stuff you retrieved from DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes sure by passing some kind of filter to your action method like below

```
public PartialViewResult ShowForm(string filter)
{ 
  if(TempData["model"]  == null)
  {  
    [...// Code]
   TempData["model"] = ModelWithData; 
  }
   if(filter == "some_condition")
    return PartialView("_FormA", TempData["model"] as ModelWithData);
   else
     return PartialView("_FormB", TempData["model"] as ModelWithData);
}
```

Got your point now. You can use any type of state management mechanish. Say `TempData`